# Chrome DevTools Protocol, page stats

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use the Chrome DevTools Protocol to access the stats that appear across the bottom of the page in the DevTools window, so requests, size of data transferred over network, size of all resources (including service worker and cache transfers), finish time, DCL event and Load event.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I've been searching through the Protocol commands and I can't find it.

Comment: It's not part of the protocol, it's calculated by devtools frontend UI. You can do the same.

Comment: OK. Do you happen to know how to do it? Are you talking about using headers in WebRequest or something else?

Comment: Call [Network.enable](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network) in the RDP, attach an event listener that will accumulate the stats.

Comment: Just coming back to this. Have you noticed that the RDP Network.loadingFinished event only reports the parser's loads, not those secondary loads initiated by CSS import statements or scripts etc. once they have loaded?

Comment: Actually it's not all secondary resources, just those in iframes which Network.loadingFinished won't report